# Autosys job fails

Tags: autosys

I have copied an autosys job, however a newly copied autosys job fails immediately with error code -655 after hitting on "ForceStart" button. With start time blank and end time displayed to be current time. 
I have changed the machine name, and box, command name for the job respectively to be the correct ones. Cannot find the root cause of failure.

Answer (score 2):

-655 is when the owner does not have access to the machine it is specified to run from. Make sure Owner has access to the run machine.